# Microsoft Dynamics 365 Plug-ins in Azure Functions and Integrate with SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, .net, azure-functions, webhooks

I apologize if this post exists, but I have not been able to find a similar one.

Is it possible to upgrade such an example:

[example](https://www.akaes.com/blog/writing-microsoft-dynamics-365-plug-ins-in-azure-functions/)

with integration to the SQL Server database, eg inserting rows?

Comment: Well, since the Azure function - by its name - runs in Azure out somewhere in the cloud, it might be a bit of a challenge to connect to SQL Server - unless you're talking about SQL Server also in the cloud somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for answer...Well, in my case, I don't have integration with  SQL to Azure yet, I'm interested in remote connection to the SQL database. Something like ado.Net or EF for data integration, but don't know how to do that in Azure Function...

Answer (score 0):

I hope following link helps to you
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup

Ugur

Comment: I don't know how familiar you are with Azure functions, but when creating, the version of Azure Functions is chosen (v1- .net framework, v2 and v3 are .net core), so this only applies to .net core... But, thanks for replay.... check hyperlink "example" for details of my problem//